# How to make div inside table same size as text inside a?

Tags: html, css, styling

How to make  inside table same size as text inside :

```
<table class="table-1">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <div class="block" id="block-1" style="background: black">
                    <a style="color: black" href="myFunc()"><c:out
                            value="${item.title}" /></a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
table.table-1 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

How to make `<div class="block" id="block-1" style="background: black">` take size of

```
<a style="color: black" href="myFunc()"> <c:out value="${item.title}"/> </a>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `display: inline-block;` for `.block`

```css
table.table-1 {
    width: 100%;
}
.block{
    display: inline-block;    
}
```

```html
<table class="table-1">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <div class="block" id="block-1" style="background: black">
                    <a style="color: #fff" href="myFunc()">text text text</a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```